# Ao inserir, value fica incorreto

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ao verificar o insert montado no **PHP** com as informações do formulário, consigo perceber que o value do campo `data_final` não é captado corretamente, gostaria de saber o que está errado, pois acredito que seja uma questão de formatos.

Desde já agradeço as sugestões.

função que resulta na `data_final`:

```
function calcula(){ 
      var periodo  = document.getElementsByName("periodo")[0].value;
      var dt1      = document.getElementsByName("datahora_inicial")[0].value;
      var val_t    = document.getElementsByName("f")[0].value;
      var parametros = {
              method: "GET"
      };

      fetch("php/calcula.php?periodo=" + periodo + "&dt1=" + dt1 + "&val_t=" + val_t, parametros).then(function(resposta) {
          return resposta.json();
      }).then(function(retorno){
          console.log(retorno)
          document.getElementById("dtfim").value = retorno;                         
      });
  }

<label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Fim</label>//campo data 
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control round-input" name="datahora_final" required="required" id="dtfim" onchange="verifica();" value="" disabled="disabled"> 
 </div>
```

insere.php

```
$datahora_final   = $_POST['datahora_final'];
$datahora_final   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datahora_final);
$sql               = "INSERT INTO tabela(data_fim) VALUES ('$datahora_final')";

//Ao inserir, sql da data retorna este valor:
'1970-01-01 01:00:00'
e o seguinte erro:
Undefined index: datahora_final
```

Comment: Um `var_dump($_POST['datahora_final'])` retorna o que?

Comment: O mesmo que citei acima

Comment: Seu código parece estar incompleto, ou completamente confuso. No código JavaScript você faz uma requisição GET para o arquivo `calcula.php`, mas você apresentou o código de `insere.php` que nem é chamado no trecho apresentado e obtém os valores em `$_POST`. A própria função `calcula` do Javascript não é chamada no código apresentado, mas uma função `verifica`, que não foi apresentada, é chamada no evento `onchange` do `input`. Você cita o campo `data_final` e no código há `datahora_final`; eles são o mesmo campo ou você não postou o trecho que contém o primeiro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o campo datahora_final está sendo preenchido com data no formato 20/05/2017 então o problema é no `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datahora_final)` faça assim:

```
$datahora_final_sem_formatar   = $_POST['datahora_final'];
$datahora_final   = substr($datahora_final_sem_formatar,6,4) . "-" . substr($datahora_final_sem_formatar,3,2) . "-" . substr($datahora_final_sem_formatar,0,2);
```

Comment: Isso não funciona

Comment: Como assim não funciona?... o que está passando no seu Post?.... se for data do formado dd/mm/yyyy a linha que modifiquei retirando o date só faz a troca para yyyy-mm-dd para adicionar no banco, o que pode estar faltando é você inserir com " aspas...porque funciona mesmo que o seu campo no banco seja datetime, aliás se for é só acrescentar na variavel $datahora_final a hora, minutos e segundo também, caso seja pego esses valores no post

Comment: Mas eu to inserindo com aspas. E isso que você fez eu já faço, está no código que postei

Comment: Primeiro não você não está fazendo o mesmo código que postei você está usando $datahora_final   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datahora_final); que retorna uma data totalmente errada, o meu código faz isso $datahora_final   = substr($datahora_final_sem_formatar,6,4) . "-" . substr($datahora_final_sem_formatar,3,2) . "-" . substr($datahora_final_sem_formatar,0,2); para retornar a data correta formatada para inserir no banco

Comment: Segundo seu campo está como disabled="disabled" mude para readonly="readonly" se você está passando por form, pois não  passa nenhum valor se for o caso e se for por form tem que ter <form method="post"> o método post

Comment: Obrigada! Seu código só não havia funcionado anteriormente devido ao disabled.